# Пунктуация вокруг фразы в кавычках, а также заглавная/строчная ли буква внутри кавычек

Tags: пунктуация, прописная-строчная, двоеточие

**Принцип Иванова "играю, пока не выиграю, потому что когда-нибудь да выиграю" сделал его банкротом.**
В данном случае нужно ли двоеточие перед фразой в кавычках и надо ли эту фразу писать с прописной буквы?
Правила гласят:

> ...ставят двоеточие, если предшествующие цитате слова цитирующего
> предупреждают о том, что далее следует цитата:
> *Пастернак писал: «Существует психология творчества, проблемы поэтики.
> Между тем изо всего искусства именно его происхожденье переживается
> всего непосредственнее, и о нем не приходится строить догадок»*.

— но я не уверен, что в моём случае есть "предупреждение о последующей цитате".
С заглавной буквой тоже не могу разобраться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы оформил без двоеточия и с заглавной буквой:

*Принцип Иванова **«Играю, пока не выиграю, потому что когда-нибудь да выиграю»** сделал его банкротом.*

§ 51. Прямая речь внутри слов автора ([Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=154)):

> **Примечание.** Подлинные выражения (цитаты), вставленные в текст в качестве элементов предложения, выделяются кавычками, но двоеточие перед ними не ставится:
>
> *Он вспомнил пословицу **«За двумя зайцами погонишься — ни одного не поймаешь»** и отказался от первоначального плана; С криком **«Спасайте детей!»** юноша бросился в горящее здание.*
>
> Но если перед подлинным выражением имеются слова *предложение, выражение, надпись* и т. п., то перед ними ставится двоеточие:
>
> *Разберите предложение: **«Сверкнула молния, и грянул гром».***

Заглавная буква обозначает своего рода название принципа Иванова, а
относить ли слово «принцип» к словам, подобным «предложению», «выражению», как мне кажется, дело десятое. Потому что постановка двоеточия будет зависеть от структуры предложения и интонации. Например, здесь двоеточие будет не нужно:

*Предложение «Сверкнула молния, и грянул гром» придётся разобрать.*

А здесь наоборот:

*Банкротом Иванова сделал его же принцип: «Играю, пока не выиграю, потому что когда-нибудь да выиграю».*

Comment: Да, действительно, я помнил, что есть правило про подлинные выражения, но не вспомнил, где найти. Спасибо!

Comment: Александр, всё правильно, и всё зависит от конкретного предложения. Мы можем оформить дословное высказывание как член предложения, при этом используются кавычки, допускается прописная или строчная буква, но не пишется двоеточие. В других случаях мы используем классическое оформление прямой речи. Так что у вас очень хороший ответ.

Comment: @Sharon кстати, смотрите, какую в примере Александра играет роль частица "же": с ней просится двоеточие, без неё -- не просится. *Банкротом Иванова сделал его же принцип: «Играю, пока не выиграю, потому что когда-нибудь да выиграю»* / *Банкротом Иванова сделал его принцип «Играю, пока не выиграю, потому что когда-нибудь да выиграю»*.

Comment: Да, действительно. Частица ЖЕ здесь предупреждает о том, что сейчас будет рассказано, какой это принцип. Поэтому ставится двоеточие. Вот и получилось классическое оформление.

Comment: @Sharon не хочу создавать отдельный вопрос, спрошу тут. Известно, что в фразеологизмах знаки не ставятся. А если фразеологизм "нарощен" автором, он теряет свои фразеологические свойства и требует знаков по общим правилам? Например, фразеологизм: *Слушали затаив дыхание*. Авторская версия: *Слушали, затаив дыхание и чуть не затаив сердцебиение*. Правда, в такой версии, кажется, теряется переносность, ощущается буквальность...

Comment: @Nektoid  Что я могу сказать о фразеологизмах? Вы относитесь к ним как-то очень почтительно, я же не считаю их «священной коровой» и обособляю или не обособляю в зависимости от структуры предложения. Многие, оказывается, тоже так считают. Посмотрите в Нацкорпусе "затаив дыхание, затаив дыхание и". Там много примеров с обособлением. Тут дело в ударении: если не обособляем, то ударение падает на оборот; если обособляем, но и на сказуемое тоже. Вот авторы и делают выбор.

Comment: @Nektoid  У вас получился авторской такой фразеологизм, симпатичный вроде: понимание фразеологизма в прямом (буквальном) смысле и распространение его.  Это даже какой-то прием художественной выразительности. Ну и конечно, он обособляется ввиду этой распространенности.

Comment: @Sharon спасибо)